# Passing data to another View Controller doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass a array to another view controller.The data reaches there fine however  , after the receiving method has already been executed.So in the receiving method , I am processing a null array.

Here I am sending.

```
   - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
  {
      UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];
     UserProfileViewController *userProfileViewController = (UserProfileViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserProfileViewController"];


     [userProfileViewController fetchMarkerData:marker.snippet nameOfUser:marker.title];

userProfileViewController.membersDetailArray   = self.membersArray; // This is what I am sending

     UINavigationController *nv = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:userProfileViewController];
    [self.revealSideViewController popViewControllerWithNewCenterController:nv animated:YES];


 }
```

Here I am receiving the array

```
  //This executes first and shows null ... the viewDidLoad NSLog output shows after this.
   -(void)fetchMarkerData:(NSString *)typeOfMarker nameOfUser:(NSString *)username
  {
   NSLog(@"members detail array in fetch marker data - %@ ", self.membersDetailArray); // shows null
   }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSLog(@"members detail array  in View Did Load- %@ ", self.membersDetailArray);//shows data  
   }
```

Comment: in the class that is sending the array, are you sure that you have initialized the array? try doing NSLog on self.membersArray. I did this not long ago, and that was my problem

Comment: hmm yeah well, you call the `fetchMarkerData:` method BEFORE you set the `membersDetailArray`, its empty in the fetch-method, because it hasn't been set yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace theses lines:

```
     [userProfileViewController fetchMarkerData:marker.snippet nameOfUser:marker.title];

     userProfileViewController.membersDetailArray   = self.membersArray; // This is what I am sending
```

for this:

```
     //using the setter to pass your data before you call the fetchMarkerData
     [serProfileViewController setMembersDetailArray:self.membersArray]; // This is what I am sending 

     [userProfileViewController fetchMarkerData:marker.snippet nameOfUser:marker.title];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in data into the following method:

```
-(void)fetchMarkerData:(NSString *)typeOfMarker nameOfUser:(NSString *)username {
    NSLog(@"members detail array in fetch marker data - %@ ", self.membersDetailArray); // shows null
}
```

But you're not updating any properties such as the `self.membersDetailArray` (assuming it gets populated with the two `typeOfMarker` and `username` objects.

Also, don't forget to initialize the array:

```
-(void)fetchMarkerData:(NSString *)typeOfMarker nameOfUser:(NSString *)username {
   self.membersDetailArray = @[typeOfMarker, username];
    NSLog(@"members detail array in fetch marker data - %@ ", self.membersDetailArray);
}
```

I am not sure how you are wanting to store the data (an array wouldn't seem appropriate with those two objects, but at least that would solve your current problem of `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, you are calling

```
[userProfileViewController fetchMarkerData:marker.snippet nameOfUser:marker.title];
```

before you actually send the array in this line:

```
userProfileViewController.membersDetailArray   = self.membersArray;
```

Simply switch those two lines and `fetchMarkerData:nameOfUser:` should have the correct value for `self. membersDetailArray`.

Additionally, you should be aware that `viewDidLoad` does not run until the navigation controller is going to show that view, which in your case is when you call

```
[self.revealSideViewController popViewControllerWithNewCenterController:nv animated:YES];
```